# Is there any way to find out what exchange a ETH wallet was created?

Tags: mining, contract-invocation, ethereum-wallet-dapp, events, storage

I added a ETH wallet address to Genesis Mining back in 2017 for a 2 year contract. After the contract was finished it still took them a year to add the ETH to said Wallet. (long story but I did not add a wallet until the last day of the contract and they were adding ETH to a wallet i did not create, then provided me that wallet address) so I have 5 eth in a wallet i believe i did not create. But I would like to figure out where it was created. I have all the other info Etherchain can provide, date first seen, date of deposit, block number etc... Just wondering if Eth blockchain adds where it was created from, location or exchange wise.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: "no".

Long answer:
Any valid Ethereum address can receive Ether via transactions, even if the private key is not known/not yet found.
Any valid transaction can be injected via any participating node in the network.